# Logic for returning caret position for changed input

Tags: javascript, logic

I'll be thankful for feedback on how i should build a logic of returning caret position for modified input.

Case: we have an input, processed by JS to be formatted like x999y999z9999, where x,y,z - are dividers we define on case by case basis. We process and modify it as intended, but i seem to become lost in logic for returning user's caret position in context of those x,y&z of variable length. I'm even kinda inclined to build a whole complex of if\else in response to those length fluctuations, but there probably is a simpler solution, which i'm missing.

Thanks in advance!

Code example: https://jsfiddle.net/zktva4kc/

```js
function doGetCaretPosition (field) {
 if (!!field){

 var CaretPos = 0;
 // IE Support
 if (document.selection) {

  field.focus ();
  var Sel = document.selection.createRange ();

  Sel.moveStart ('character', -field.value.length);

  CaretPos = Sel.text.length;
 }
 // Firefox support
 else if (field.selectionStart || field.selectionStart == '0')
  CaretPos = field.selectionStart;

 return (CaretPos);
 }else{
 console.log("No such field exist here for function initiation.");
 }
}


function setCaretPosition(field, pos)
{
 if (!!field){

 if(field.setSelectionRange)
 {
  field.focus();
  field.setSelectionRange(pos,pos);
 }
 else if (field.createTextRange) {
  var range = field.createTextRange();
  range.collapse(true);
  range.moveEnd('character', pos);
  range.moveStart('character', pos);
  range.select();
 }
 }else{
 console.log("No such field exist here for function initiation.");
 }
}

function formatItDown(field, format) {  
 if (!!field){

    field.oninput = function () {
  var position=doGetCaretPosition(field);
  var sInput=this.value;
        var input = this.value;
        input = input.replace(/[^\d]/gi, "");

        var first = input.substr(0, 3);
        var second = input.substr(3, 3);
        var third = input.substr(6, 4);

        if (input.length > 3) {
            first = format[0] + first + format[1];
        }
        if (input.length > 6) {
            second = second + format[2];
   
        }

        formatted = first + second + third;
  //x012y456z8901
  /* this here is the problem area when we use some complex formats
  if ((formatted[3]!=sInput[3])&&(position>3)&&(position<6)){
   position=position+1;
  }else if ((formatted[7]!=sInput[7])&&(position>7)){
   position=position+1;
  }*/
  
        this.value = formatted;
  
  setCaretPosition(field, position);
    }
 

 }else{
 console.log("No such field exist here for function initiation.");
 }
}

formatItDown(document.getElementById('exampleInput'), ["--","==","__"]);
```

```html
<input id='exampleInput'>
```

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: As per your suggestion, @zer00ne , i added code to the post.

Comment: Do you want these delimiters (i.e. x, y, and z) counted when selected? I can provide you a working example I made a while back. Is there a reason why the input doesn't accept any alphabetical key? I couldn't find where in your code that would cause that behavior.

Comment: @zer00ne , a working example is always a great thing! For reference at least, so i'll be thankful)


1. "Do you want these delimiters (i.e. x, y, and z) counted when selected?"
I don't fully grasp what you mean here, but probably yes - the whole issue is that i don't correctly return caret position in context of those delimiters when user enters some amount of data.

Comment: 2. "Is there a reason why the input doesn't accept any alphabetical key?"
Yeah, it was intended that way (through [input = input.replace(/[^\d]/gi, ""); ]). This function is essentially a template for a number of pre-formatted numberish input fields for phone, zip and alike.

Answer (score 0):

Why not quickly google for something well coded and bug free ?

Here is a good plugin I used once

https://github.com/acdvorak/jquery.caret

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but i'm pretty  
content with current caret get-return functions - they seem to work fine. The issue lies in that i can't seem to grasp the full logic of _how i should process_ that position in context of modified line.